# Windows Phone WebBrowser set cookies

Tags: .net, cookies, browser, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am using HttpWebRequest for REST services which uses some basic authentication that relies on JSESSIONID cookie. I need to pass that cookie to WebBrowser control to reuse that session, but didn't find any usable solution that would allow me to pass that cookie in the Browser's cookie store.

Is there any way? The only way that I can think of now is to use Naviagate(url, null, MANUALLY_CONSTRUCTED_HEADER) which is kind of brute-force.

Yes, and really have to use WebBrowser for this kind of action.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to put Cookie to header but WebBrowser ignored just this one header. This was my last hope and now it's broken. What now?

Comment: [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrl, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData); does not work on WindowsPhone.

Comment: I think this cannot be done. Windows Phone is useless in this way. Fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another thought is that you might be able to add cookies via JavaScript. You should be able to do this (provided IsScriptEnabled is true on your browser control):

```
private void setCookie(string name, string value, string path = "", string domain = "", bool isSecure=false, string expires = "")
{
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("document.cookie = '{0}=\" + escape(\"{1}\")", name, value);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(expires))
            sb.AppendFormat(";expires=\"{0}\"", expires); // should be a GMTString
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            sb.AppendFormat(";path=\"{0}\"", path); 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
            sb.AppendFormat(";domain=\"{0}\"", domain);
        if (isSecure)
            sb.Append(";secure'");
        var cookieJs = sb.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(cookieJs);
        webBrowser.InvokeScript(cookieJs);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was another concept I have already tried. It seems to work, but I was forced to abandon it because you cannot invoke javascript when the browser is navigation (which was my case) and I was unable to properly detect the moment that the navigation was finished (when you cancel navigation, Navigated event is not fired).

Comment: iam getting an Error "An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006." While trying this code in navigated event of Webrowser control

Comment: @achukrishnan Not sure where I did this when I was trying my code out where I put the cookie, but OnNavigated event means that you already got to the page. You might want to try onNavigating or some other point in your code..

Comment: God bless you. This needs to be invoked in WebBrowser's LoadCompleted event.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by sending JSESSIONID in URL for the first time, which then obtained the valid JSESSIONID cookie. But this is not an universal approach.

I think that there is solution which will navigate to simple webpage, that's nested within the application resource. The browser can then invoke javascript function, which will set the cookies passed by parameters. If Microsoft does not interfere with such approach (by disablink document.cookie), this can be a solution (I haven't tested it yet).

Comment: this is the only working solution i know too. But this needs server side customization to get it working. I hope Microsoft will support cookies in apps and browsercontrol better in wp 8.1 api. This is functionality needed in many business cases.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are getting exception on invoking script even on LoadCompleted event, try this out:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.cookie = \"COOKIE_NAME=" + COOKIE_VALUE + "; Path=/; Domain=" + WEB_URL.DnsSafeHost + " ;\";");
```

This one worked for me on LoadCompleted event. Keep in mind you have to load twice to get cookie functional. On LoadCompleted, cookie will be injected but not shown, on second load though, it would work fine.