# Set cookie in Windows Phone WebBrowser control

Tags: cookies, webbrowser-control, windows-phone

How do I add custom cookies to Windows Phone WebBrowser control?

Comment: See here for a similar question/answer - [Windows Phone Set Cookies][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287409/windows-phone-webbrowser-set-cookies/13367748#13367748

Answer (score 1):

There is no set cookie function with the WebBrowser control. It does not make sense to have one because you can only set cookies for sites you own. So the cookie should be set on the page you are loading (navigating to) inside the browser. This can easily be done with JavaScript. There are other methods using CookieContainer and accessing the request object through the scripting functions of the WebBrowser control, but the JavaScript options is the simplest.