# Pass cookie to WebBrowser in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am currently developing an app that uses a public API. After performing the login procedure with that API, I get a cookie that I store in my app. I need to pass this cookie with every API call, that I request. So far so good.

Now unfortunately this API doesn't give me acces to all features of the service. What I want to do is giving the users of my app a button, which open a WebBrowser for that specific features. The problem is, that the user is, of course, not logged in in that WebBrowser.

What I found out on my PC is, that the login-cookie, that I get from the API, would actually work for the website itself as well. So what I want to do is: When the user clicks on the button, it opens the WebBrowser and passes the login cookie I already have to the WebBrowser, so the user is already logged in and can use the feature. Is there any solution for that problem? I couldn't an answer for that.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set cookies from invoking javascript on the page when loading is completed.
[Windows Phone WebBrowser set cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287409/windows-phone-webbrowser-set-cookies)